# ggplot polar_coord space out text better

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data in the data frame `times.posix`. Since it's time data,  I want to visualize it as a circular histogram. My code is this:

```
ggplot(times.posix) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = pct.hour(dropoff.posix) ), bins = 24, color = 'black', fill = 'blue') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:23, labels = paste( (11:(11+11) )%%12 + 1, c(rep('AM',12), rep('PM', 12) ) ) ) +
  ggtitle('Dropoff time frequency') +
  coord_polar()
```

and my graph ends up like this

[image]

The actual geom_hist ends up fine but the text around it is weirdly spaced - the labels seem alright starting at 12AM but by 11PM theyre a full block behind. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: @Tjebo Where? I count 24 boxes, 24 labels. Which part do I have 25 of? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with the `pct.hour` function. I'm not sure what this function is, since the required libraries aren't included in the question and I can't find any documentation online.

If you instead use `lubridate::hour`, the problem seems to vanish:

```r
ggplot(times.posix) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = lubridate::hour(dropoff.posix)), 
                 bins = 24, 
                 color = 'black', 
                 fill = 'blue') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:23, 
                     labels = paste((11:(22)) %% 12 + 1, c(rep('AM', 12), rep('PM', 12)))) +
  ggtitle('Dropoff time frequency') +
  coord_polar()
```

[image]

However, I can replicate your undesired plot if any of the values of x are 24, for example:

```
geom_histogram(aes(x = lubridate::hour(dropoff.posix) * 24/23))
```

Gives

[image]

So my guess is that if you do `max(pct.hour(times.posix$dropoff.posix))` you will get 24, when it should be 23. If you let us know what the `pct.hour()` function is, perhaps we can help see where the problem really lies.

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(69)
times.posix <- data.frame(dropoff.posix = as.POSIXct("2020-03-13") + 60 * runif(500,0,1440))
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. "pct.hour" was just my way of doing (hour + minutes/60), but I must've forgot to mod by 24, giving me some times >= 24:00. Thanks for that, should've realized there should only be 23 bins.